# Apache2 now pointing to new default page

Tags: 14.04, apache2

My Apache2 server has a new default page: `Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page` (located at `/var/www/html/index.html`)

All my webserver served files are at: `/opt/lampp/htdocs` folder.

Why has this change happened and how to fix it?

Comment: You did `sudo apt-get install lampp` or `sudo apt-get install apache2`?

Comment: Not within the last few years

Comment: This issue has happened again (after an update). Totally infuriating.

Answer (score 4):

Apache2 from the Ubuntu repository gets it's default location from `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

The default page configuration is the `000-default.conf` file in that location.

You can either modify that page or use it as a template and make your own configuration file.  If you want to have a page with the location of `/opt/lampp/htdocs` as it's server route you can do that in this manner:

1) Copy the `00-default.conf` file to a new name.  For an easy method to remember to purpose, you can call the filename, `mywebsite.conf` to have the configuration for `www.mywebsite.conf`.

Now edit this new page with these changes:

**Change from:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**change to:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName www.mywebsite.com
        ServerAlias mywebsite.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs

        # We must also allow access to the new root directory; by
        # default only access to /var/www is allowed.
        <Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs>
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

After you have created the virtual host for your website, enable this new configuration with:

```
$ sudo a2ensite mywebsite.conf
```

The system will then prompt you to restart the server for the changes to take effect, which you can do with:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

**The two important changes are:**

1. ServerName
2. DocumentRoot

Now you can you will be able to access your website by the name given in the ServerName or the ServerAlias directives.

I left the comments in the configuration files example to show the options that can be enabled by removing the "#" desired option.  Also the comments are a valuable resource explaining the configuration options.

Comment: `sudo systemctl restart apache2` says command not found.
Strangely the default is not working but sites under the root are fine. I am using http://<machine-name> as the root folder.

Comment: **Which version of Ubuntu are you running?**  Before 16.04 the command to restart apache2 was **`sudo service apache2 restart`**.  By the way, the latter will work in both 14.04 and 16.04.  All the sites are working based on the `httpd.conf` setting.  The method you used for installing Apache2 makes a difference to where the configuration is read from.  That is why muru asked you how did you install it.  I assumed you had run the latter (`sudo apt-get install apache2`) based on the details of your original question.

Comment: There are several other inaccuracies in this answer which I am too lazy to correct. Most importantly, files are read from `/etc/apache2/site-enabled`, and also copying the file to one with a new name will not have the desired effect if the name of the new file alphabetically comes after that of the old one.

Comment: @fkraiem The two items you mentioned appears to be misunderstandings on your part.  While you mention there are a number inaccuracies, the same might be in effect with the other items you thing are inaccuracy.  I don't mind explaining the parts you are getting the wrong impression.  I also appreciate pointing out any components that might not be correct.  The copy reference is copying a working template "`00-default.conf`" to a new name, making the needed changes to the working template for your intended virtual site.  (continued)...

Comment: ... (continued).  The reference to where Apache2 is getting the configuration is two parts.  The user edits the `sites-available` file and enables the ones he wants included with the `a2ensite` which I included in the steps.

Comment: The server gets its configuration from `sites-enabled`, period. The common practice of first creating a file in `sites-available` and then "enabling" it with `a2ensite` is just to make adminitration easier, and does not change the fact that, ultimately, the server only cares about what's in `sites-enabled`.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  It is my effort to make things easy for the OP and people trying to use the system.  I believe editing and manually placing files in the sites-enabled directory can become a confusing mess.  Working with the sites-available folder and enabling the ones you want to be effective is so much easier.  Trying to rewrite all the documentation in every answer might become a bit cumbersome and confusing to many also.  Referencing to where to place the pertinent files and how to enable your choice is as **your words**... quote: "**`make administration easier`**".

Comment: Rebooted the computer...all back to normal! Thanks guys! Love you lots <3 <3 <3

(sorry if you got offended by what  I wrote - just a symptom of my stress)

Comment: By the way. This was fixed and has now re-occurred. Should I re-open this issue. The question now is why is it happening regularly? Something to do with the Software Updater?

Comment: While there are a number of different ways suggesting to handle it, my answer is focused on using the default Ubuntu repository solution for the Apache2 install.  This way it won't change with normal updates.  The answer suggests using the `00-default.conf` file as a default template.  Make a virtual host with your desired settings.  The answer shows what you need to apply to your virtual host, which needs to be a unique file.  Once you enable your **virtualhost** configuration, it will always run and pint to what you have in the settings of that file.

Comment: @JohnnyBizzle Will you edit your question and place the content of your **mysite.conf** file?  Of course you can call that file by any name, but the content has to be specific.  Using the steps provided in the answer your actual web files could be anywhere on your computer's network.

Comment: @L.D.James It is working again. I did not do anything. Not sure why it does this from time to time. :/
As most of the local files are uploaded to an internet site, for me this is a minor issue. I will check these files if it happens again.